# selecting all rows which has value > 1 in r

Tags: r

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zhOa.png)i have a data and want to select all rows which has value > 1 in r.
i tried 
sel <- apply(data[,collist],1,function(row) "1" %in% row)
 but it is not working and give me whole a data frame,

```
[data set][1]
```

how can i subset these data?

thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  he first col is just character"ACAP3" and the rest of heading  column names has a combination of number and characters"A-3 A- A9J". when i tried the first command did not give the correct output and the second command give me total NA.

Comment: I have transferred my comment to an answer with reproducible input and output so you can see that it works.  Copy and paste the code shown in the Note at the end to your R session and then copy and paste the code in the answer to reproduce the output shown in the answer. Then figure out what you have differs and look up all commands in the help files.

Comment: Also, if you want responders to use exactly your data then you need to provide it in reproducible form and, in fact, not doing so might result in your question being closed as that is expected from all questions. To do that cut it down to a reasonable size and then show the output of `dput(data)`.  Be sure that your example includes some rows that should be included and some rows that should be excluded.  Also show the expected output.  See [mcve][ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The Note at the end shows the data used in the examples below.  I have changed the headings as shown since the ones provided in the question are unwieldy and have removed the column of minus signs.

**1)** Using that data, the correct answer to the question of selecting all rows with a 1 in any column is that only the first two data rows are selected and that is, in fact, what happens:

```
subset(data, A == 1 | B == 1 | C == 1)
##       Sym A B C
## 1   ACAP3 0 0 1
## 2  ACTRT2 0 0 1
```

**2)** This version does not make use of the headings:

```
has1 <- rowSums(data == 1) > 0
data[has1, ]
##       Sym A B C
## 1   ACAP3 0 0 1
## 2  ACTRT2 0 0 1
```

**3)** Although the above should work it would be a bit safer to just check the numeric columns which for this data can be done like this:

```
has1 <- rowSums(data[-1] == 1) > 0
data[has1, ]
##       Sym A B C
## 1   ACAP3 0 0 1
## 2  ACTRT2 0 0 1
```

**4)** or if we did not know which columns were numeric:

```
is.num <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
has1 <- rowSums(data[is.num] == 1) > 0
data[has1, ]
##       Sym A B C
## 1   ACAP3 0 0 1
## 2  ACTRT2 0 0 1
```

### Note

As the question did not provide input in reproducible form, the input shown in such form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- 'Hugo_Symbol "A - 3 A- A9J" "B - F2 - 7273 - 01" "C - FB - AAPP - 01"
ACAP3 0 0 - 1
ACTRT2 0 0 - 1
AGRN 0 0 - 0
ANKRD65 0 0 - 0
ATAD3A 0 0 - 0
'

data <- read.table(text = Lines, skip = 1, col.names = c("Sym", "A", "B", "X", "C"),
 colClasses = c(NA, NA, NA, "NULL", NA))
```

The above produces this:

```
data
##       Sym A B C
## 1   ACAP3 0 0 1
## 2  ACTRT2 0 0 1
## 3    AGRN 0 0 0
## 4 ANKRD65 0 0 0
## 5  ATAD3A 0 0 0
```